# why python is available from python.org in .msi format for windows platform, rather than the traditional .exe format?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Why python is available in .msi format in python.org for windows platform. 
Why isn't it available in the conventional .exe format?

Here, what are the advantages of .msi format, compared to .exe format?

Comment: This Question has nothing to do with programming. Please have a look at what topics you can ask here at Stack Overflow http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: `.exe` is executable file while `.msi` is an installation file. anyway, this not related to `Python` programming at all

Comment: Consider dropping the Python-specific parts of the question and ask "What are the differences between .msi and .exe installers?", or "How would I choose between using an .msi or .exe installer for my project?"

Answer (score 2):

**MSI** Is a database file.

It can contain a cabinet file, with binary data, but it is not required.
The MSI database is used to tell a "package manager" how to install a program.
This will in all normal windows installations be "msiexec" (The built in microsoft windows installer).

The database holds information about which files to copy where, what to write in the windows registry, which programs to run after files are copied, and similar information.

The advantages of using a package manager, is that the program can be easily uninstalled, repaired, or upgraded after initial installation.

**EXE** is an assembly, (program).

Depending on who wrote it, it could be a very good tool, a stand alone program, an installer, an autoextraction of a zip file, a virus, a hacker tool, or all of the above. You have no way of knowing without reverse engineering it, or trying to run it..

Tools exists that can build an executable which basicly just runs msiexec on an embedded msi file. Thats desireable if you dont want the users to modify the database and redistribute it.

The list of pros and cons are longer.

Answer (score 0):

MSI is the file extension for [Windows Installer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer). It's perfectly fine for an installer to have this extension.